# How to smoothly interpolate between points in two-dimensional space?

Tags: math, graphics, interpolation, curve, spline

Let's say I have a number of points, each defined by an X and Y coordinate in a two-dimensional cartesian coordinate system. The X coordinate of every point is greater than the one of its predecessor, so there can't be any loops.

How can I draw a smooth line through these points? The result should look something like a sine wave, but with varying amplitude and wavelength. It's absolutely fine if it is simplified or approximated as long as it allows me to calculate the Y coordinate of the interpolated points without using any library functions for lines or splines. Language doesn't matter, I'm interested in the algorithm, not the implementation. For full disclosure, I plan to implement it in JavaScript.

I'd like to stay away from complicated math like Bézier splines or something with control points. I feel there must be a simple solution that maybe works with the distance to the points or something like that.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an interpolating polynomial. There are a number of ways you can fit it. Try reading this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Constructing_the_interpolation_polynomial

If you have a large number of points, then you may consider wanting to use an approximation instead otherwise you could suffer from overfitting and poor representation of your data between points. In that case, you could use least-squares polynomial approximation. It depends on the degree of accuracy that you need.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Linear_least_squares

In particular, if your data is sinusoidal, you can actually approximate data using trignometric basis functions (sine or cosine functions of different integer frequencies) instead of regular powers of x.

Alternatively you can interpolate using splines in a non parametric way that does not involve control points

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Using splines will prevent you getting the potential wild oscillations that you can get using basic high degree polynomial interpolation.

As with all approximation problems, it is hard to give a definitive answer without seeing the data (and the amount of it). Ultimately though if you have a large number of data, basic polynomial interpolation is not your friend as if you have 1000 points to interpolate, you need a 999 degree polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid "complicated" math here. And it is not that much complicated.

Cubic splines is good solution for your problem. For the similar task I found [this](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Pixar/spline77.pdf) paper with short explanation and a matrix which I used for my computations.

You can try using approximation methods. "Least squares" and its modifications are one of the simplest, and easy to implement.